# Python format phone number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How would I go about formatting a 10 digit string: `0123456789` to phone number format:

> (012) 345-6789

Is there a specific library to use or can you use regex?

I've done it the other way around by using `re.sub('[^0-9]', '', '(012) 345-6789')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import re
print('(%s) %s-%s' % tuple(re.findall(r'\d{4}$|\d{3}', '0123456789')))
```

This outputs:

```
(012) 345-6789
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use a library like [`phonenumbers`](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers)?

Install it:

```
pip install --user phonenumbers
```

Code Sample:

```
import phonenumbers 
phonenumbers.format_number(phonenumbers.parse("0123456789", 'US'),
                           phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL)
```

Output:

```
'(012) 345-6789'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using **`re.sub`** lets you handle output string formatting in a single command.

```
import re
s = '0123456789'

>>> re.sub(r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})', r'(\1) \2-\3', s)
'(012) 345-6789'
```

Answer (score 3):

Slice the string into the parts you need separated, such as the first three numbers for the area code, [(slicing tutorial)](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/)
then concatenate the parts and formatting together, [(concatenation tutorial)](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python).

```
num="0123456789"
print("("+num[:3]+")"+num[3:6]+"-"+num[6:])
```

Answer (score 1):

To enhance Mike's response a little:

```
def parsephone(strphone):
    '''
    Pull out just the digits. Then do some simple formating.
    '''
    phn = ""
    for n in strphone:
        if n in "0123456789":
            phn += n
    if len(phn) == 10:  # add a 1 in front
        phn = "1" + phn
    if len(phn) != 11:
        return phn  # no hope of formating
    # format with dashes
    phn = phn[:1] + "-" + phn[1:4] + "-" + phn[4:7] + "-" + phn[7:]
    return phn
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`clean_phone()`](https://sfu-db.github.io/dataprep/user_guide/clean/clean_phone.html) from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/). Install it with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
>>> from dataprep.clean import clean_phone
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'phone': ['0123456789', 1234567890]})
>>> clean_phone(df, 'phone', output_format='national')
Phone Number Cleaning Report:                                                   
    2 values cleaned (100.0%)
Result contains 2 (100.0%) values in the correct format and 0 null values (0.0%)
        phone     phone_clean
0  0123456789  (012) 345-6789
1  1234567890  (123) 456-7890
```